# missing platform exception error for shared preferences and flutter toast plugin in iOS flutter

Tags: android, ios, flutter, dart

I uploaded my application on play store but, when I create IPA for flutter app, then I received these two errors:

> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method showToast on channel Ponnam Karthik/flutter toast)
>
> Unhandled Exception: MissingPluginException(No implementation found
> for method getAll on channel plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences)

This is my flutter doctor summary:

```
[✓] **Flutter (Channel stable, v1.12.13+hotfix.8, on Mac OS X 10.15.2 19C57, locale en-IN)**
 
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 29.0.3)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 11.3)
[✓] Android Studio (version 3.5)
[✓] Connected device (1 available)
```

I changed the plugin version. Already used flutter clean and reinstall application, but I can't get it working.

Anyone know how to solve this issue?

```
Future<List> mainLogin() async {
  final response = await 
  http.post("$api_version/authentication/signin",
  body: {"email": email, "password": password});
    datauser = json.decode(response.body);

    if (datauser.length == 0) {
    setState(() {
    msg = "Login Fail";
    });
  } else {
    if (datauser['error_description'] == 'Invalid Login Details') {
      searchScaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
      showLoginError(
        context, datauser['error_message'], 
        datauser['error_description']
      );
    } else if (datauser['success'] == 1) {
      searchScaffoldKey.currentState.hideCurrentSnackBar();
      Fluttertoast.showToast(
        msg: datauser['success_description'],
        toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
        gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
        timeInSecForIos: 1
      );

      //===============================================
      //Create a session of user

      SharedPreferences loginCresentials =
        await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      loginCresentials.setString('User_id', datauser['results']['id']);
      loginCresentials.setString('User_email', datauser['results'].['email']);
      loginCresentials.setString(
        'User_fname', datauser['results']['first_name']
      );
      loginCresentials.setString(
        'User_lname', datauser['results']['last_name']
      );
      loginCresentials.setString(
        'User_password', datauser['results']['plain_password']);
      loginCresentials.setString('userType', datauser['results'].['userType']);
      loginCresentials?.setBool("isLoggedIn", true);

      Navigator.pushAndRemoveUntil(
        context,
        MaterialPageRoute(
          builder: (BuildContext context) => MyHome(
            initialIndex: 0,
          )
        ),
        ModalRoute.withName('/')
      );
    } else {
      SharedPreferences loginCresentials =
      await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
      loginCresentials?.setBool("isLoggedIn", false);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share what package you are using for the `Toast` and the code where you are using it. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @JoãoSoares   fluttertoast: ^3.1.3. and shared_preferences: ^0.5.6+1

Comment: Please share the code where you are using the `showToast`.

Comment: @JoãoSoares  actually i called api, check response if success == 1 then      `Fluttertoast.showToast(
        backgroundColor: Colors.red,
          msg: "Google Authentication Success",
          toastLength: Toast.LENGTH_SHORT,
          gravity: ToastGravity.CENTER,
          timeInSecForIos: 4); `
else failed.

This works fine in ANDROID but WHY IT NOT WORK IN IOS

Comment: Please place the code in the question instead of the comment section.

Comment: quetion is posted

Comment: Have you attempted to run a simple example with FlutterToast on both Android and iOS, separate from all of your other code. Just a view with a button to trigger the toast? It will help debug this issue.

Comment: yes i already tried this

Comment: And it also doesn't work?

Comment: yes this is also not working

Comment: is there any permission for use shared preferences and flutter toast for iOS??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use flutter clean command first, and then re-run the application

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while using flutter toast dependency and social media login dependencies like google, Facebook, and Twitter.
I followed these steps and resolved it:

1. First, u need to test whether these toast and shared preference dependencies are causing problems or some other dependency are the cause.
2. For testing that, u need to create a new seprate flutter project having the same flutter toast and shared preference dependency and check now if u r able to get toasts or not.
3. If u r getting toast so there is no problem with ur toast dependency.
4. The problem might be in ur one of the social media dependency.

In my case, I followed the above steps and found that problem was in facebook dependency. I did not register my app at Facebook developer's console and so reimplemneted that and my app was fine.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue currently and found out that the problem is caused by facebook_auth package. 
But my app still need to use Facebook login, how can I solve this problem?

Comment: @Alvindrakes did u register ur app at Facebook developer's console ?

Comment: Found the problem. Basically, the facebook auth package needs to be setup 1st on Android before running the app (in debug / release mode etc).

After setting up everything, the problem is solved =)

Answer (score 0):

If you override the **configureFlutterEngine** method in your **MainActivity** class then you will need to register all the plugins by calling **GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(FlutterEngine)**. See example bellow.

Don't forget to run **flutter clean** to clear all cache.

Hope this helps you all.

```
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity;
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine;
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant;

public class MainActivity extends FlutterActivity {

  @Override
  public void configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull FlutterEngine engine) {
   
    // register plugins
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(engine);
  }

}
```